# opening org link in dired

Tags: dired, microsoft-windows, org-link

[[D:/dev::line][code]] stores the link to my code directory. How can i used dired to open it in emacs. Currently with this code explorer opens the directory. I'm using Windows 7.

Comment: I hope that I understand right that `D:/dev` is a directory. I do not understand what the search `::line` means in that case.  If `D:/dev` is a directory you could try `(add-to-list 'org-file-apps '(directory . emacs))`. You can customize the variable `org-file-apps` with `Options` -> `Customize Emacs` -> `Specific Option...`. Insert a new Cons cell with `INS`, First Choice: `Links to a directory`; Second Choice: `Visit with Emacs`. I post this as a comment rather than an answer since I am not sure whether I understand right what you are asking.

Comment: The search `::line` would mean that you jump to a line matching `line` in the dired buffer (I just tested it, it would work.) In my previous comment I forgot to mention that you need to click on `Apply` to accept the settings in the Customization buffer for the current session.